# ASP.Net Razor Syntax display SQL SelectQuery values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, razor

I am trying to combine multiple count queries in to one and so far get expected results in SSMS but I need to display it in my webpage which is in ASP.Net Razor Syntax.

```
var selectQuery= SELECT COUNT (Host) AS Total,
COUNT CASE (WHEN OS LIKE '1909%' THEN 1 END) AS Win101909,
COUNT CASE (WHEN OS LIKE '20H2%' THEN 1 END) AS Win1020H2
FROM Computers;

var ComputerCount = db.QueryValue(selectQuery);

<p>@ComputerCount.Total</P>
<p>@ComputerCount.Win101909</P>
<p>@ComputerCount.Win1020H2</P>
```

Am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this it was as below:

Change: `db.QueryValue(selectQuery);`
To: `db.QuerySingle(selectQuery);`

It may help someone else